# Copy files from folders and sub-folders to another folder and saving the structure of the folders

Tags: r, file

I have created a list of files by some conditions and I want to copy only the files from that list to a new folder and subfolders like in the origin folder.
The structure of the folders is year/month/day.

This is the code I tried:

```
from.dir <- "J:/Radar_data/Beit_Dagan/RAW/2018"
## I want only the files from the night
to.dir   <- "J:/Radar_data/Beit_Dagan/night"
files    <- list.files(path = from.dir, full.names = TRUE, recursive = 
TRUE)
## night_files is a vector I created with the files I need - only during the night
for (f in night_files) file.copy(from = f, to = to.dir)
```

But I get all the files in one folder

part of my list look like this:

```
[1] "J:/Radar_data/Beit_Dagan/H5/2018/03/10/TLV180310142554.h5"
[2] "J:/Radar_data/Beit_Dagan/H5/2018/03/10/TLV180310142749.h5"
[3] "J:/Radar_data/Beit_Dagan/H5/2018/03/10/TLV180310143054.h5"
```

Is there a way to keep the structure of the folder and the subfolders when copying?
I want to get the same structure of year/month/day in the new "night" folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the flag `recursive = T` inside the copy call, so you don't really need to loop inside the dir.

`from = paste0(getwd(),"/output/","output_1")
 to = paste0(getwd(),"/output/","output_1_copy")
 file.copy(from, to, recursive = T)`

Note that you need to create the `/output_1_copy` directory previously to the call. Yo can do it manually or using `dir.create(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need:

```
file.copy(from = from.dir, to = to.dir,recursive=T)
```